# youtube oauth works from localhost, but not from production

Tags: oauth, youtube, youtube-api

The website I'm making makes it possible to connect your account with your youtube account. From localhost, this works perfectly, but from the site, which is step1tuts.appspot.com, it doesn't work. When I redirect the user to the authentication page from my website, I get the following message:

> The page you have requested cannot be displayed. Another site was
>   requesting access to your Google Account, but sent a malformed
>   request. Please contact the site that you were trying to use when you
>   received this message to inform them of the error.

The code that handles this authentication looks like this:

```
client = youtube.get_client()

client.developer_key = 'AI39si759T7YcZ4E3XvICpZr3cGwQ0Ev4AjwyJrVSS6AW6NUc7_t10DX1JsngWzU4YoGjpsjAUTejav0hgXp9vDuM7a83tDXzQ'
client.client_id = 'step1tuts.com'

domain = 'http://' + os.environ['HTTP_HOST']+"/user/youtube_token"
scope = 'http://gdata.youtube.com'
url = client.GenerateAuthSubURL(domain,scope,secure=False,session=True)
self.redirect(str(url))
return
```

The url I'm redirecting to, ending in /auth_token then processes the token it gets back from youtube, but the error happens here.

Just for clarity, the youtube.get_client method is one that I developed to reuse the process of making the client appengine ready: the code for that is:

```
def get_client():
    client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    run_on_appengine(client)

    client.developer_key = 'AI39si759T7YcZ4E3XvICpZr3cGwQ0Ev4AjwyJrVSS6AW6NUc7_t10DX1JsngWzU4YoGjpsjAUTejav0hgXp9vDuM7a83tDXzQ'
    client.client_id = 'step1tuts.com'
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if(user and user.yt_token):
        client.SetAuthSubToken(user.yt_token)
    return client
```

While pasting in this code, I noticed that I'm duplicating the part where I give my developer key. I don't think that that's the problem, but I'll remove that from the authentication part of my code, and see what happens.

The problem must be tracable by watching the url that the user is redirected to, so just for some extra info, the url that I'm redirected to when I'm using the app on my local machine using the SDK, with which it works:

http://www.youtube.com/auth_sub_request?scope=http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com&session=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fuser%2Fyoutube_token%3Fauth_sub_scopes%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgdata.youtube.com&secure=0&hd=default

And the url that I'm redirected to when I use the same code on production:

http://www.youtube.com/auth_sub_request?scope=http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com&session=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstep1tuts.appspot.com%2Fuser%2Fyoutube_token%3Fauth_sub_scopes%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgdata.youtube.com&secure=0&hd=default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. All other urls work except this one. Probably a bug on youtube side? I just added a '.' at the end of your domain and the request seems to go through. Maybe you can try that?

[http://www.youtube.com/auth_sub_request?scope=http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com&session=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstep1tuts.appspot.com.%2Fuser%2Fyoutube_token%3Fauth_sub_scopes%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgdata.youtube.com&secure=0&hd=default](http://www.youtube.com/auth_sub_request?scope=http://gdata.youtube.com&session=1&next=http://step1tuts.appspot.com./user/youtube_token?auth_sub_scopes=http%253A%252F%252Fgdata.youtube.com&secure=0&hd=default)